# Rails associations for a model 'owned' by many Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, has-many, model-associations

I have a simple rails app that functions as a cms for a digital signage application.
In this app, there will be a pool of predefined styles that I want to offer to all users.
Every style includes a background picture, some css and a video.

My goal is to get a setup where I can prepare different styles, add them using rails admin and every user should have a menu where he can choose one of the styles as **active_style** for his account.

Sounds easy, but the point where I'm stuck is the associations between the **User** and the **Style** models. 
 I tried different things for several hours (has_many: / has_many_though / has_and_belongs_to_many), but I cannot get to the point where each user can pick one of the style objects and make it their active_style, and allow just **one** active_style at a time.

I just wonder what is the best way to do this and would be very happy if someone could help out. 
 I'm relatively new to rails programming, please excuse if this seems stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it sounds unintuitive, but I think the association you want in this case is "belongs_to". I say it's unintuitive because it sounds strange saying "a user belongs to an active style", but "has_one" would not allow a single style to be the active style for multiple users.

The following code assumes you have an "active_style_id" integer column on your Users table that will store the foreign key:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :active_style, class_name: 'Style'
end
```

This will then let you do things like:

```
style = Style.find(...)
user = User.create(active_style: style)
user.active_style # => style
```

Comment: Thank you Beerlington!
Great answer, this is exactly what I wanted. You're also right about the "unintuitive" nature of this :) This was exactly what kept me from using the belongs_to. I thought when i use it i could not allow a single style to be active for several users, but obviously it is exactly the other way around. Thanks a bunch!